# What is the best URI template for retrieving grouped counts of a particular resource in a REST API?

Tags: web-services, rest, uri

I have a REST API which exposes a URI to return a collection of employees in JSON. The URI is of the following format:

```
http://webservice/employees
```

I now want to expose a URI which returns the number of employees grouped by, say, the office they work in and further information about the office. For example:

```
items: [{
           officeId: 1,
           officeName: "Big Office",
           switchboardTel: "123456789",
           numEmployees: 100
        },
        {
           officeId: 2,
           officeName: "Small Office",
           switchboardTel: "987654321",
           numEmployees: 30
        },
        ... // etc.
       ]
```

What would be a suitable URI for this? I am thinking that given it returns information about the offices (along with the number of employees), then perhaps this information should be retrieved via the "offices" resource:

```
http://webservice/offices
```

Alternatively, would the following URI be more suitable?

```
http://webservice/employees?groupBy=office
```

In my opinion, this seems slightly wrong as the response returns information about the offices, rather than the employees, along with an employee count.

Say I then wanted to expose a URI which returned the number of employees grouped by their age... would this belong to the "employees" resource, such as:

```
http://webservice/employees?groupBy=age
```

...or would it be better suited to creating an "ages" resource:

```
http://webservice/ages
```

In my opinion, the "groupBy=age" option seems best here...but then that kind of makes the URI formats slightly inconsistent.

Basically, I want a consistent URI format to get a count of employees grouped by some criteria - and for the response to contain information about the grouping.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tom